# Google Translate Cloud API, not translating correctly

Tags: python, text-to-speech, google-translate, google-text-to-speech, google-translation-api

I have recently started using Google cloud translate API with python. M having trouble converting this word in the Telugu language which is written in English "parishkaram chesamu".  In general internet or mobile the application google translate which we use is giving correctly. But API is returning the same word again.

Google Cloud translate API:

Input text: parishkaram chesamu

Output text: parishkaram chesamu

parameters :

```
text ='''parishkaram chesamu'''
target = "en"
output = translate_client.translate(text)

print(output)

{'translatedText': 'parishkaram chesamu', 'detectedSourceLanguage': 'te', 'input': 'parishkaram chesamu'}
```

================================

Mobile or Internet google translate:

Input text : parishkaram chesamu

Output text: We have solved

Answer (score 0):

based on my comments, trying to figure out a solution for this as well, I offer up my version of a solution for this problem.  The only tested flow that I can get to reliably work, is the following:  (I'm using google cloud translate)

```
Step 1: translate your message into a language, it doesn't matter which.
Step 2: get the detectedLanguageCode value from the results in step 1
Step 3: run a transliteration on the original message, with the value from step 2. (I'm using google's deprecated translit API), with thanks to @Ali for providing it!
Step 4: re-run step 1, modifying the original message to be the transliterated output in step 3.
```

This is a snippet from my code to show the exact pseudo-flow. (I removed the error checking, back pressure, etc. complexities).

```
    // run request
    let [response] = await translate(request);

    request['contents'][0] = await transliterate(request.contents[0], response.translations[0].detectedLanguageCode);

    [response] = await callWithRetry(request, interaction, channel);
return response;
```

Transliterate is based on the published link above, which I harvested and setup as this:

```
    const url = `https://inputtools.google.com/request?text=${srcMessage}&itc=${srclang}-t-i0-und&num=${numChoices}&cp=0&cs=1&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&app=demopage`;
```

where srcMessage is the original text, srclang is the output from step 2, and I set numchoices (the number of possible did-you-mean-this transliterations to 1)