# Google Cloud Translation from Russian to English does not work when Russian is not in Russian alphabet

Tags: google-translation-api, google-cloud-translate

I am using v3 Google Cloud Translate API ([projects.translateText documentation](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/reference/rest/v3/projects/translateText)). I have noticed that when I translate from a language with one alphabet (ie. Russian) to a language with another alphabet (ie. English) using characters from the second alphabet, that the API is not translating the text in the response. Instead it is returning the text in the second alphabet but is successfully detecting the source language.

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70246066/google-translate-cloud-api-not-translating-correctly?rq=1) which I think is maybe the same and is saying to use the spell check API which seems disappointing.

## Examples

**1. Requesting Russian word(s) in Russian alphabet to be translated to English.**

Request

```
{
    "targetLanguageCode": "en",
    "contents": ["Привет"],
}
```

Response

```
{
    "translations": [
        "translatedText": "hello",
        "detectedLanguageCode": "ru"
    ]
}
```

This returns as expected. It both detects Russian and translates to English.

**2. Requesting Russian word(s) in English alphabet to be translated to English.**

Request

```
{
    "targetLanguageCode": "en",
    "contents": ["Privet"],
}
```

Response

```
{
    "translations": [
        "translatedText": "Privet",
        "detectedLanguageCode": "ru"
    ]
}
```

This does not return what I would expect. It successfully detects the language as Russian but fails to translate the text to English. When I use the Google Translate website and do the same thing it works as I would expect the API to work. [Translation Example](https://translate.google.com/?sl=ru&tl=en&text=privet%20&op=translate).

## I Have Tried

- Setting the source language explicitly to "ru" instead of letting it auto detect

## Questions

- Is this intended behavior?
- Is there some other way to get the API to return the translation?

Comment: How are you using  API Translate? Were you using the API explorer? Because I tried API translator via curl and it worked on my end. Please check following documentation for the step by step process: https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/advanced/quickstart

Comment: I have the same issue as the original submitter.  Trying to translate Russian, or Hindi, using English characters, correctly identifies the phrase as the target language, but returns nonsense.  The API fails, and the web version of google translate does this correctly.

Comment: Looks like the spell-check API (referred in the question's original text) is indeed the answer...

Comment: @G-Force, just like the OP, what method are you using? You can check the quickstart, it was working when I tried using via curl method.

Comment: i use node, and that basic quick start flow was what I used to build it, and works fine except for this case.  you're saying that curl/powershell method for you will work without a need for going to the spell check step as well? @AnjelaB

Comment: I used the curl method, as you described @AnjelaB, and my input text is "ye kya hai yaar", which, when selecting EN as the destination language, repeats exactly the same as the input text.  Cyrillic does the same thing too.

Comment: @G-Force, for hindi, there is an existing issue for that. Here is the tracker: [link](https://b.corp.google.com/issues/189744674) You can also refer to this SO post for complete details [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70765855/google-translator-is-not-working-with-gujrati-language-written-in-english)

Comment: @AnjelaB, thanks for the links.  It's not just Hindi that has the problem, it's any transliteration.  I have found a solution which works in general cases, but it is costly.  run translation on the input, get the targetlanguage detected back, run the google transliterate call and get the native suggestion equivalent, and then resubmit to the translate engine.